# Possible Mistaken Empty Statement C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

Here's my code. I have counterpart set to 20 and I get the warning possible mistake empty statement with these lines. My goal is to increase speed to make it harder as you go. The same problem happens when I just enter the number 20. As of now it just adds .75 each time.

```
if(speed < counterpart);
            {
                speed += 0.25F;
            }
            if(speed > counterpart);
            {
                 speed += 0.5F;
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove those semicolons from the end of your `if` statements.

Because of them, you're *always* running both statements in the curly braces. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
if(speed < counterpart);  // empty 'if' statement, doing nothing even if true

speed += 0.25F;

if(speed > counterpart);  // same here

speed += 0.5F;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

Both blocks get executed, because you have semicolons (`;`) behind your if statements, so they're not doing anything. Try this:

```
if(speed < counterpart)
    speed += 0.25F;

else if(speed > counterpart)
    speed += 0.5F;
```

Note: I also added an `else` on the second if statement to prevent the second statement from executing, if the first one succeeds.